# How to read until last non-empty cell

Tags: r, excel, import

When reading data from excel and specifying a range like A1:D10, is it possible to say A1:last row and column you find data for (= is not empty)?

What is the syntax for this?

Thx

Comment: This depends on what you are using to import an Excel file. If you use `readxl` you can specify the columns and rows, along with the sheet, you want to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and even though it is late for you, might be useful for others.

Use `read_excel` function with specified file and sheet as you would normally. And then specify the `range` with `anchored` function, where you specify the cell you want to start with as the first argument and dimensions  `dim` as the second argument. You specify number of rows and columns or put `NA` if should go until the last row/column.

So for example if I want to start from B4, get 6 columns until last non-empty row I use:

```
read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet = 'sheet1', range = anchored("B4", dim = c(NA, 6)))
```